# Does anyone know why this library affects the design of my application? (firebaseui)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

This is the api

`compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'`

It affects the size of my `RecyclerView`, example without adding the library, the size is suitable that you indicate, and at the time of adding that library the "rectangles" of my `RecyclerView` become too large.

These changes occur when I install the application on some device.

Comment: can you tell me, which `google play services` version you are using?

Comment: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Comment: try using `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:9.8.0'`

Comment: Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:9.8.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/9.8.0/google-services-9.8.0.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/9.8.0/google-services-9.8.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/9.8.0/google-services-9.8.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/9.8.0/google-services-9.8.0.jar
Required by:
    :Alquileres:unspecified

Comment: Follow this procedure in android studio: open Tools menu -- SDK manager -- Launch Standalone sdk manager -- Extras folder (last in the list) -- google play services --> update this package and do sync project again

Comment: ready, but still the same

Comment: i just needed to update Google repository

Comment: there could be some compatibility issue. You can go through [FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)